# Regarding a warning message in JAGS for R

Tags: r, bayesian, rjags

I am experimenting with `rjags` `r` package while learning Bayesian. I fitted following multivariate model using tobacco data set in `rrr` package.

[image]

where \gamma is a random intercept which measures the correlation between the outcomes.  Also I purposefully make some values of the response as missing to explore the results with a unbalanced structure of the data. At the same time, I added AID variable which denotes the subject ids.

I fitted this model using `rjags` as follows.

```
library(rrr)
require(dplyr)
library(rjags)
data("tobacco")
tobacco <- as_data_frame(tobacco)

tobacco$AID=seq(1:25)
tobacco[4,1]=NA
tobacco[14,1]=NA
tobacco[8,1]=NA
tobacco[6,2]=NA
tobacco[1,2]=NA
tobacco[19,2]=NA
tobacco[21,2]=NA


N1=length(tobacco$Y1.BurnRate)
bayes_model_mul="model {
for(i in 1:N1){
Y1.BurnRate[i]~dnorm(mu1[i],tau1)
Y2.PercentSugar[i]~dnorm(mu2[i],tau2)
mu1[i]=beta1[1] + beta1[2]*X2.PercentChlorine[i] + beta1[3]*X3.PercentPotassium[i] + gamma[AID[i]]
mu2[i]=beta2[1] + beta2[3]*X2.PercentChlorine[i] + beta2[2]*X1.PercentNitrogen[i]+
beta2[4]*X3.PercentPotassium[i]+gamma[AID[i]]
gamma[i] ~ dmnorm(0,tau_u)

}
for (l in 1:3) { beta1[l] ~dnorm(0, 0.001) }
for (l in 1:4) { beta2[l] ~dnorm(0, 0.001) }
tau1 ~ dgamma(.01,.01)
sigma_tau1 = 1/tau1 

tau2 ~ dgamma(.01,.01)
sigma_tau2 = 1/tau2

tau_u ~ dgamma(.01,.01)
sigma_tau_u = 1/tau_u 
}"


model3 <- jags.model(textConnection(bayes_model_mul), 
                     data = list(Y1.BurnRate=tobacco$Y1.BurnRate,
                                 Y2.PercentSugar=tobacco$Y2.PercentSugar
                                 ,X1.PercentNitrogen=tobacco$X1.PercentNitrogen,
                                 N1=N1,X2.PercentChlorine=tobacco$X2.PercentChlorine,
                                 X3.PercentPotassium=tobacco$X3.PercentPotassium,AID=tobacco$AID),
                     n.chains=1)
params <- c('beta1','sigma_tau1','sigma_tau2','beta2','sigma_tau_u','gamma')
samps.1 <- coda.samples(model3, params, n.iter = 10000)
burn.in=1000
summary.model.1=summary(window(samps.1, start = burn.in))
```

I didnt get any error. But I got following warning message.

```
Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : start value not changed
```

Can anyone help me to figure what is this error message is about ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `window` function is used to select a range of samples. It takes `start` and `end` parameters. The value that `start` takes should be greater than the the sum of the number of iterations passed to `n.adapt` in `jags.models` and `n.iter` in `update`, if explicitly setting a number of burnin samples.

You can have a look at the object retuned by `jags.model` to see how the number of iterations changes.

```
# Define the model
model3 <- jags.model(textConnection(bayes_model_mul), n.adapt=1234,
                     data = list(Y1.BurnRate=tobacco$Y1.BurnRate,Y2.PercentSugar=tobacco$Y2.PercentSugar,X1.PercentNitrogen=tobacco$X1.PercentNitrogen,N1=N1,X2.PercentChlorine=tobacco$X2.PercentChlorine,X3.PercentPotassium=tobacco$X3.PercentPotassium,AID=tobacco$AID),
                     n.chains=1)
# Look at the number of iterations (== n.adapt)
model3$iter()
#1234

# Add some burnin iterations: iterations are updated to n.adapt + burnin
update(model3, n.iter=1111)
model3$iter()
# 2345

# Draw more samples -> iterations updated to n.adapt + burnin + n.iter
samps.1 <- coda.samples(model3, n.iter = 10000, variable.names=c('beta1','sigma_tau1','sigma_tau2','beta2','sigma_tau_u','gamma'))
model3$iter()
# 12345
```

When we use `window` the start value is expected to be greater than `n.adapt + burnin` as these iterations have been discarded. If it is not then a `start` value is extracted from the `coda.samples` object (see `mcpar(samps.1[[1]])`) and your manual `start` value is not used.

So using `w=window(samps.1, start=2345)` gives the warning that you see

> Warning message:
> In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : start value not changed

But the following is okay as the `start` is greater than `n.adapt + burnin`

```
w=window(samps.1, start=2346)
```

Remember these are just warnings and in this case are not that important. But if you rerun `coda.samples` without rerunning `jags.model` this will again update the iterations which makes it a bit harder to track what values to pass to `window` (and can then throw errors)

Comment: In [this](https://www.rensvandeschoot.com/tutorials/rjags-how-to-get-started/) tutorial, it uses a `burnin` of 500, `n.adapt` is unspecified so it should default to 1000, but `start` is only set to 500 - yet it does not produce the "start value not changed" warning. Why is this? (given you are saying that it expects `start` to be greater than `n.adapt + burnin`)

Comment: Hi @bob; they dont use the `update` function in that tutorial, so no explicit burnin. They just cut the first 500 iterations using the `window` function, so as `start=500` is less than "*n.adapt in jags.models and n.iter in update*" (e.g. 1000) there is no warning.

Comment: But because `start=500` is less than `n.adapt=1000`, there should be a warning, right? The `n.adapt` samples should have been discarded, thus needing to start at 1001 in order to avoid the warning.

Comment: Hi bob; Yes my previous comment was wrong ... a couple of years since i looked at this, sorry.  For the model at the link, if you run `model.fit$iter()` after the `jags.model` stage it returns `0`, which I assume there is no [adaptation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rjags/versions/4-13/topics/adapt) done as (probably) a conjugate model is fit. Hence, the start value will be greater than zero hence no warning.  ...

Comment: ... (ps if you run `mcpar(model.samples[[1]])` ; the first value is `n.adapt(jags.model) + n.iter(udpate) + 1`, and the `second n.adapt(jags.model) + n.iter(udpate) + n.iter(coda.samples)` and the third in thin)

Comment: ... and a quick look at the samplers (after running the model) using [runjags](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runjags/vignettes/quickjags.html) indicates that they re all conjugate

Comment: Thanks for circling back on this. Your response was insightful and helped a lot! What I understand is that even if I specify `n.adapt = 1000`, you're saying it ignores that because it realizes it's a conjugate model and thus doesn't need adaptation. Makes sense! Also didn't realize that `model.fit$iter()` is different before and after `coda.samples(model.fit ...)` is run (aka didn't realize `coda.samples()` changes the `model.fit` object directly.

Comment: If we were to not specify `n.adapt` as in this case (thus letting it default to 1000), would any prespecified `model.inits` get ignored? @user20650

Comment: what do you mean by `model.inits` please @bob ? Do you mean the `inits` argument in `jags.model`? If so, no it shouldn't be ignored.. Do you have a specific example in mind that is not playing the way you expect?

Comment: Yep, I mean the inits argument, sorry. When I run `model.fit$state()[[1]]` after the `jags.model()` call, it does not reflect my initial values. However I think this might be the iteration state _after_ adaptation, thus making sense that it's does not reflect the inits I specified. Is there any way to see the chain starting from my inits? Not seeing how to get it out of the object created from `jags.model()`.

Comment: Yes, it appears the values returned by  `model.fit$state()` are not equal to the starting values for a model that requires adaptation. I am not aware of how you could get those values; and they are likely not retuned as they aren't very useful ..> will not be a Markov chain.

Comment: you could ask at https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/ . the author is responsive

Comment: Gotcha, will do! @user20650 - thanks!