# understanding the output of str function in R

Tags: r

I use the str to print out information for a calculate variable

```
str(samples)
 'mcmc' num [1:1000, 1:228] 0.1079 -0.2367 -0.0757 -0.3414 -0.3382 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:228] "B[1,1,1]" "B[2,1,1]" "B[3,1,1]" "B[4,1,1]" ...
 - attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 20005 25000 5
```

But how to read these information, or what does this output can tell us? For instance, the third component is `attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 20005 25000 5`, what does it mean?

Comment: Looks like a Monte Carlo Markov Chain and `"mcpar"` seems to be the mc *par*ameters.

Comment: for counting the iterations [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507610/regarding-a-warning-message-in-jags-for-r/63508245#63508245) may provide a wee bit of info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attr` implies there is an attribute named 'mcpar' which is a `numeric` vector

```
attributes(samples)
```

returns a `list` of all the attributes of the samples i.e. it will return `dimnames` as one attribute and the 'mcpar' as another one

According to documentation

> The ‘mcpar’ attribute of an MCMC object gives the start iteration the end iteration and the thinning interval of the chain.

Comment: thanks, is that possible for you to share the link of the documentation you referrred

Comment: In accordance with the str output, the first attribut is mcmc, and it corresponds to a1000*228 matrix, is that right? Thanks

Comment: @user288609 In your post, it is not clear from which package you are using.  But I assumed from code.  Here is the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/coda/man/mcpar.html)